# How to make a route from main.dart to my Home Screen page in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making an application of one page which is the Home Screen but I want to separate my main.dart flutter page from the Home Screen page , how can I make a route that links the pages in the source file by only clicking on

```
home: const HomeScreen()
```

?

My main.dart page

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'home_screen.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const HomeScreen()
      }
    );
}
}
```

My home_page.dart file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `main.dart` uses `HomeScreen` as body so you have only page to link another one
just use Navigator:

```
Navigator.push(context, route);
```

For example:

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context){
  return const ExamplePage();
}));
```

Where `ExamplePage()` is your separated page.